# Application Getting Crashed

Tags: java, android

I am trying to apply Pin Lock in one of my application. It's getting crashed on with `Fatal Exception`.
My Main Activity Class is like below

```
public class LockActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "PinLockView";
    private PinLockView mPinLockView;
    private IndicatorDots mIndicatorDots;

    private PinLockListener mPinLockListener = new PinLockListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String pin) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pin complete: " + pin);
        }

        @Override
        public void onEmpty() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pin empty");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPinChange(int pinLength, String intermediatePin) {
             Log.d(TAG, "Pin changed, new length " + pinLength + " with intermediate pin " + intermediatePin);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPinLockView = (PinLockView) findViewById(R.id.pin_lock_view);
        mPinLockView.setPinLockListener(mPinLockListener);
    }
}
```

Its giving runtime error in this line

```
     com.exmaple.myapp.LockActivity.onCreate(LockActivity.java:42)
```

What I am missing in this?

LOGCAT is like below

```
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826): Process: it.dueelleautomazione.plcmon, PID: 28826
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.dueelleautomazione.plcmon/it.dueelleautomazione.plcmon.LockActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.andrognito.pinlockview.PinLockView.setPinLockListener(com.andrognito.pinlockview.PinLockListener)' on a null object reference
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.andrognito.pinlockview.PinLockView.setPinLockListener(com.andrognito.pinlockview.PinLockListener)' on a null object reference
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at it.dueelleautomazione.plcmon.LockActivity.onCreate(LockActivity.java:42)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
09-20 09:09:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(28826):    ... 9 more
```

Thanks

Comment: post your error here

Comment: Post your full log

Comment: *"What I am missing in this ?"* Showing us the full stacktrace so we might have a chance to help you.

Comment: @Tony @ driodev I have added log cat

Comment: What is PinLockView ?

Comment: @Andreas I have added it now...Thanks

Comment: You are missing setContentView call

Comment: @driodev its lock view of library used from this...https://github.com/aritraroy/PinLockView

Comment: Instead of posting such simple qns try to find yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss this

```
setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_XML_LAYOUT_FOR_LOCKACTIVITY);
```

after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`